# Create PDF with Coldfusion (openBD CFML engine) java

Tags: java, coldfusion, aspose, openbd, bluedragon

Wrestling to create PDF in Coldfusion using the following block with no success:

```
<cfset FileInputStream = CreateObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream") >
<cfset File = CreateObject("java", "java.io.File")>

<cfset lic = CreateObject("java", "com.aspose.pdf.License")>
<cfset lic.setLicense(FileInputStream.init(File.init("E:\Tomcat\webapps\openbd\Aspose.Pdf.lic")))>


<cfset Document = CreateObject("java", "com.aspose.pdf.Document").init() >
<cfset demo_pdf = Document.init() >

<cfset Section = CreateObject("java", "aspose.pdf.Section").init() >
<cfset Text = CreateObject("java", "aspose.pdf.Text").init() >

<cfset sec1 = section.demo_pdf.getSections().add() >
<cfset sec1.getParagraphs().add(Text.init("Τέσσερα"))>
<cfset demo_pdf.save("E:\Tomcat\webapps\openbd\HelloWorld.pdf")>
```

The error produced is: "java.lang.NoSuchFieldException" on line:"cfset sec1 = section.demo_pdf.getSections().add()".
What am i supposed to do in order to generate PDFs using java aspose PDF lib under openBD CFML engine?

Comment: The easy way to create a pdf with ColdFusion is with the cfdocument tag.  Do you have a reason to not use it?

Comment: He is using OpenBD, not ColdFusion. That could be the reason for not using `cfdocument`. Also, I would argue that `cfdocument` is not the easiest way to create properly formatted PDFs. @anarchos check out http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ easy to use and apply formatting.

Comment: The reason that i don't use cfdocument is that the PDFs that i generate is not in supported by openBD engine language [greek fonts]. Same issue on Railo.

Comment: @Scott Stroz. How do i use it in conjunction with openBD?

Comment: First, you would need to build the content in HTML and save that HTML to disk. Next, you use `cfexecute` to call the wkhtml2pdf process to generate the PDF and write it to disk. Next, you would use `cfcontent` to serve up the PDF (and delete it if you want). Finally And optionally, delete the HTML file from disk. Sounds like a lot, but it is pretty easy, actually.

Comment: You _may_ run into the same font issues with wkhtml2pdf, but I am not certain.

Comment: @Scott Stroz. At a first glance, it seems not to have any issues with the fonts. 1 up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to your last comment, try the following code:

```
<cfset demo_pdf = CreateObject("java", "aspose.pdf.Pdf").init() >
<cfset section = CreateObject("java", "aspose.pdf.Section").init() >
<cfset sec1 = demo_pdf.getSections().add() >
<cfset text = CreateObject("java", "aspose.pdf.Text").init("Κατά τη συζήτηση") >
<cfset text.getTextInfo().setFontName("Arial Unicode MS")>
<cfset sec1.getParagraphs().add(text)>
<cfset demo_pdf.setUnicode()>
<cfset demo_pdf.save("c:\HelloWorld.pdf")>
```

Answer (score 3):

I work as Social Media Developer at Aspose. You need to use "aspose.pdf.Pdf" class instead of "com.aspose.pdf.Document" class. See the following updated sample:

```
<cfset demo_pdf = CreateObject("java", "aspose.pdf.Pdf").init() >

<cfset section = CreateObject("java", "aspose.pdf.Section").init() >
<cfset text = CreateObject("java", "aspose.pdf.Text").init("Hello World") >

<cfset sec1 = demo_pdf.getSections().add() >
<cfset sec1.getParagraphs().add(text)>
<cfset demo_pdf.save("c:\data\HelloWorld.pdf")>
```

**Update based on comments:**

You can add `<cfset demo_pdf.setUnicode()>` before the save statement to include the TrueType font to be used for your Greek Charaters.

Comment: @Aslam I accept this answer, but after a trial i figured that aspose library cannot print Greek like: `Κατά τη συζήτηση`.  Is there any way to draw Greek characters?

Comment: You can add <cfset demo_pdf.setUnicode()> before the save statement to include the TrueType font to be used for your Greek Charaters.

Comment: @Aslam. Could you give me an example? How to add TrueType Fonts.